# Hibernate, Partial Class

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate and I am facing with a really annoying problem, when i re- generated my Business Object and mapping files because a new property o structural change or something the old files are complete overwriting, then my validation, calculated properties, my personalization  like EAGER or LAZY load and all my job in the old files are lost. There is anyways to solve this problem like merge generation, or like .net Partial class (one the generated  code , the second one for my personalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually put all custom code in sub-classes of the generated code to avoid that problem. You can also add Java code in the XML files and the generation process puts it in to the generated classes. IMO that's a pain because you lose the advantages of coding in a Java-aware editor.

Answer (score 1):

A rather drastic option is to stop using hbm with code generation files and use hibernate annotations.

I've been using this style for the last 4 or so years and haven't looked back, there is minor duplication of editing to say add a field but even that is pretty painless give you probably want to add additional metadata/validations to the field in hibernate anyhow.